# Realm.Manage update

Tags: xamarin, realm

How do I update a Manage Realm object?

If I run this twice it fails, saying the object is already managed.  I understand the Exception, but how do I update/delete the object after it is managed?

```
        using (var instance2 = Realm.GetInstance())
        {
            using (var transaction = instance2.BeginWrite())
            {
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    instance2.Manage(item);
                }
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to Manage an object a second time. Once it's been added to the Realm by calling `Manage`, it becomes a "live" object - every change you make will be persisted. So if you have a list of employees:

```
var instance = Realm.GetInstance();
using (var transaction = instance.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var e in employees)
    {
        instance.Manage(e);
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

And then you want to, say, calculate their salaries, you could simply do:

```
using (var transaction2 = instance.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var e in employees)
    {
        e.Salary = CalculateSalary(e);
    }
    transaction2.Commit();
}
```

As you can see, there's no need to call `Manage` again, you just have to set whatever properties you want to update within a write transaction.